# помогите упростить код функции js

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

```
function del_category(block, path, options, set){
 this.delete_block = block; // блок который будет удалятся
// this.id = options.id; // id 
 this.path = path;

   this.del = function(id, block_del){
      if(set){ 
        $.get(this.path, {id:id}, function(data){

      });

      }
       block_del.remove();//(".specification_wrap").remove();
 }
var _this = this;
 this.delete_block.on('click',  function(){
     //alert('asda');
    _this.del($(this).parent().parent().find("input").attr("ids"), $(this).parent().parent());
 });
  }
```

Это код функции который удаляет блоки и посылает ajax запросы, хочу его как-то упростить и сделать компактным. Суть функции заключается в прикреплении события к элементу затем запускается удаление запросом к php и в случае успешного процесса блок в котором находилась кнопочка удалить должен исчезнуть.

Answer (score 2):

Не прикрепляйте событие к элементу. Просто повесьте на него ф-ю. Вот пример:

```
$("#id_кнопки").on("click", function(e){
    var el = this;
    $.get("url",
          {json},
           function(response){
               $(el).parent().remove();
           },
       "json");
});`
```

Comment: `this` внутри обработчика указывает на объект `jqXhr`, а не элемент по которому кликнули

Comment: @Grundy паправлина

Answer (score 0):

```js
const PARENT_SELECTOR = '.category';
const BUTTON_SELECTOR = '.item';
const URL = window.location.href; // your current url
const ANY_METHOD = 'JSON';
const ANY_DATA = {test: 'test'};

$(document).on('click',BUTTON_SELECTOR, async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let $currentElement = $(event.currentTarget);
  await fetch(URL, {
    method: ANY_METHOD,
    body: ANY_DATA // - if NOT GET/HEAD
  })
  $currentElement.parents(PARENT_SELECTOR).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='category-list'>
  <li class='category'>
    <p>Category 1</p>
    <ul>
      <li class='item'>Item 1.1</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 1.2</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='category'>
    <p>Category 2</p>
    <ul>
      <li class='item'>Item 2.1</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 2.2</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='category'>
    <p>Category 3</p>
    <ul>
      <li class='item'>Item 3.1</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 3.2</li>
      <li class='item'>Item 3.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```